# Invalid column name even though I am only selecting if that column is not null?

Tags: sql

I ran into this issue creating some stored procedures today. It started off with me getting a message that a column didn't exist. That's not out of the ordinary - we have hundreds of databases so sometimes things go missing.

However, when I tried to add the column to the table that was missing them, things got weird.

Check out these two code samples:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MNTSetup') 
BEGIN
    IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.MNTSetup','VehicleChecklistEMail') is not null
    BEGIN
       select VehicleChecklistEMail from dbo.MNTSetup
    END
END
```

This one errors out. However, if I try to run this one:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MNTSetup') 
BEGIN
    IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.MNTSetup','VehicleChecklistEMail') is null
    BEGIN
       --i put code to show the db name here
    END
END
```

This shows that there are NO results!

So my SQL is basically telling me that there are no existing MNTSetup tables with a missing email column and yet when I try to select on that column I get this error.

What could possibly be happening?

Comment: What do these 2 queries return?   SELECT COL_LENGTH('dbo.MNTSetup','VehicleChecklistEMail')  and 
  SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MNTSetup'

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql to solve your issue. In your first query, sql engine will NOT know your IF clause (or better, will ignore your IF clause) result, and will simply try to parse your query, and then finds that column [VehicleChecklistEMail ] does not exist, thus error out

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being some database corruption. If you end up experiencing the same thing I have, you will need to take steps to troubleshoot the hardware or software and get the corruption resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the table name in first query. Also, Instead of `SELECT * FROM` with exists, use `SELECT 1 FROM`

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MNTSetup') 
BEGIN
    IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.MNTSetup','VehicleChecklistEMail') is not null
    BEGIN
       select VehicleChecklistEMail FROM dbo.MNTSetup
    END
END
```

Comment: Even when adding the "FROM dbo.MNTSetup", I still get the error. "Invalid column name VehicleChecklistEMail

Answer (score 0):

Check this query and if there will be no result, change your schema name 'dbo' to the schema for the table. I suspect that the schema is not 'dbo'.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MNTSetup'
              AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') 
BEGIN
    IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.MNTSetup','VehicleChecklistEMail') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       SELECT VehicleChecklistEMail 
         FROM dbo.MNTSetup
    END
END
```